# Run-time error 1004 - opening a workbook hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to write a simple code for looping through some .xls files from a Japanese site. While making the framework I run into a Runtime 1004 problem - www.e-stat...could not be found, yet the the files are available. Here's the code. If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong, that'd be splendid. PS - I've tried looking for the answer everywhere on the internet.

```
Sub automate()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filepath As String
Thswb = ThisWorkbook.Name

'Worksheets("data").Activate
'Dim namearray As Integer
 Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Integer

MyArray(1) = 0
MyArray(2) = 1
MyArray(3) = 2
MyArray(4) = 7

For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)

        Workbooks.Open "www.e-stat.go.jp/SG1" & "/estat/XlsdlE.do?sinfid=00002723131" & MyArray(i)
        'Do stuff
        'In progress  
        ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully qualify the URL with the protocol and assign its handle to wb.

```
Sub automate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim filepath As String, Thswb As String, i As Integer
    Thswb = ThisWorkbook.Name

    'Worksheets("data").Activate
    'Dim namearray As Integer
     Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Integer

    MyArray(1) = 0
    MyArray(2) = 1
    MyArray(3) = 2
    MyArray(4) = 7

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("http://www.e-stat.go.jp/SG1" & "/estat/XlsdlE.do?sinfid=00002723131" & MyArray(i))
        With wb
            'Do stuff
            'In progress
        End With
        wb.Close
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

I ran your code with the above modification and was able to open all 4 workbooks.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. I truly appreciate it. Thanks again!